# How can I access my component state through destructuring?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object-destructuring

I'm trying to access the this.state.timeRemaining value from within the componentWillMount() function. I've destructured the this.state object and renamed the value to "swag". I expect my console.log() statement to print out "5" (as I have set the state and run this print statement in the callback function) but the value of "null" is printed instead. I believe this is a destructuring specific issue as I am able to print "5" by using this.state.timeRemaining in the console.log() statement instead. Any ideas why this is? Does this have anything to do with the context?

```
class Favr extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {detailsAreShowing: false, timeRemaining: null};
        this.showDetails = this.showDetails.bind(this);
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        const { timeRemaining: swag } = this.state;
        const { favr: {expirationTime} } = this.props;
        let remainingTimeInMil = expirationTime.getTime() - Date.now();
        this.setState({timeRemaining: 5}, () => {
            console.log(swag); // prints null
        });
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are reading the declared variable at the first line of `componentWillMount` method which it's not updated. Even if you do not rename it it will print `null` as well. When you read `this.state.timeRemaining` again it provides the updated value.

Comment: Hmmm, I was under the impression that I was merely referencing the state value when declaring my destructured state constant. Is there a recommended way that I could destructure and maintain access to the latest state values?

Comment: Exactly. Nope, you just read it again when you need or read after update it which seems it's your case.

Answer (score 0):

There is a problem with your understanding and using of variables and references in JS.

- By destructuring / deconnstructing `const {timeRemaining: swag} = this.state`, you are creating a new variable `swag`. This variable will have new memory allocated to it, updating `timeRemaining` will not change value of `swag` as at the time of assignment, `timeRemaining` has value of `null`. Assignment by referencing only works with `object` in JS.
- Also, not directly related to your question, but it's worth knowing that it's never a good idea to use `componentWillMount` with `React`. This lifecycle method has been deprecated since React 16.3: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillmount.